# how to find the length of a side of hexadecagon in relation to the radius or diameter.

Tags: polygons

is there an equation I can use to find the length of a side (L) of a regular hexadecagon (16 sided polygon) based on its radius (by which I mean the length from the center to on vertex) or its diameter (twice that... duh)? That would be really helpful.

Comment: wikipedia and math central, as well as searching Mathematics StackExchange

Comment: Haha! No, I mean, what have *you* done to try to solve it?

Comment: I'm in seventh grade... I haven't taken geometry yet.

Comment: Oh shoot. Well, it may be hard to follow my answer then. If you need me to explain anything, just ask. Do you know what the sine function is?

Comment: No I don't sorry.

Comment: Hmm. I don't think you can use the formula without knowing what the sine function is. Here's a wikipedia article that should give you the basic idea: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine

Comment: Did that help at all?

Comment: Sorry, definitely

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a right triangle to solve the problem. Suppose we are given the side length $l$ and that the polygon has $16$ sides. Then we can create a right triangle by joining the center $C$ of the polygon to the midpoint $M$ of one of its sides and then to a vertex $V$ of that same side. Since the polygon has $16$ sides,
$$m\angle A=\frac{360^\circ}{32}=11.25^\circ$$
and now we can solve for the hypotenuse of the triangle. Since the short leg of the triangle is half of the side length of the polygon, if we let $h$ be the length of the hypotenuse, we have
$$\sin A=\frac{\frac{1}{2}l}{h}$$
$$\sin 11.25^\circ=\frac{l}{2h}$$
$$h=\frac{l}{\sin 11.25^\circ}$$
And this is the formula you're looking for.

If this is difficult to follow, let me know and I'll draw a picture to go with my answer.